# How to update multiple square bracket strings at once using PHP

Tags: php

I work on multi-language website and I'm struggling with single quotes. Some sentences have single quote inside it and some not.

My question is how I can use `sQuote` function to use it for all strings which starts from `$lang`?

**PHP**

```
function sQuote($string) {
  return htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES);
}

$lang['login_0'] = 'text 1 \'';
$lang['login_1'] = 'text 2 \'';
$lang['login_2'] = 'text 3';
$lang['login_3'] = 'text 4';
$lang['login_4'] = 'text 5 \'';
$lang['login_5'] = 'text 6';
$lang['login_6'] = 'text 7 \'';
```

**HTML**

```
<?=sQuote($lang['login_0'])?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$lang = array_map(function($value) { return sQuote($value); }, $lang)
```

Comment: `array_map('sQuote', $lang)`…